# What kind of knob fits a slotted potentiometer shaft?

Tags: identification, potentiometer, component-selection

What I thought was an easy question is more elusive than I suspected. I have a number of potentiometers that have smooth (not knurled) shafts with a slot cut into the end...it looks like a flathead screw.

[image: similar to this, from Mouser's site]

I need a knob for it, but can't find one. I suspect I don't know the right thing to ask for. When I google "knob slotted potentiometer" or similar, I get a ton of pots drowning out anything I might hit for noise, and no useful links if I search for "slotted knob" "knob for slotted" etc.

While a set screw would likely work I'd prefer to get something that's made for the shaft I'm working with. Does someone know what I'm looking for and what search terms I need to use to effectively filter out the pots from the knobs?

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer and PN of the pot?

Comment: It was a grab-bag box-o'-pots I bought at a garage sale. There's an  assortment of pots from various manufacturers, a lot of BI Technologies & Alpha, other unmarked/unidentifiable. However, they all have smooth 1/4" shafts with slots ~2-3mm deep.

Comment: A large amount of knobs fit that kind of pot. It's fairly standard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The slot is for adjustment with a flat-headed screwdriver (instead of a knob), and is not generally intended as a feature for the knob to engage with.  Just use the same type of knob that you'd use with a purely cylindrical shaft - a knob with a setscrew:

[image]

Comment: Well then. That's a great reason I wouldn't be able to find a specific pot for this shaft. Set screws it is! Thanks.