# Flush/slotted actuated rotary switch knob?

Tags: switches, identification, component-selection

I'm thinking of using the [R10015RS02Q](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/R10015RS02Q/CKN9478-ND/1949297) SP10T rotary switch for an upcoming project I'm working on.

[image]

It's marketed as having a flush/slotted type actuator which I think requires something like a flathead screwdriver to rotate.

What I'd really want is for it to be hand actuated, however all the knobs I've found are meant to be used for a shaft-type rotary switch. I know it's possible to get a shafted SP10T rotary switch, but in my research it's cheaper to get these flush/slotted kinds.

My question is are these flush/slotted actuator devices ever intended to be used with a  knob/hand actuated, or am I looking in all the wrong places for a knob?

As a side note, what are these slotted rotary switches usually used for/with (if anything)?

I know this is awfully close to a shopping-type question, I'm justifying it as valid because of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/52067/what-kind-of-knob-fits-a-slotted-potentiometer-shaft) which asks what type of knob to use with a round shaft potentiometers.

Comment: This switch is not meant for your needs, but there are nice small not expensive ones made for rotating by fingers without using tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rotary switch under discussion is typically used for preset / factory setting or maintenance purposes - such as for setting a part of a device address, a configuration value to be read during device operation, or selection of power path for enabling one of several circuit sub-sections.

The particular part you have selected has silver-plated copper contacts (`Q suffix`) for power routing, rather than low-level signal routing or configuration setting.

The lack of available knobs for this type of switch aligns with the design goal of not making it convenient for end-users to make changes - like having a sticker "*No user-serviceable parts inside*".

For a hand-actuated equivalent, look for flatted actuator, or knob actuator designs. Some **thumbwheel** actuated designs are also very cost-effective, especially [on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/EECoSwitch-ThumbWheel-Switch-10-POS-5V-701ML-/220371719556?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item334f2d9584) or other such sites.

[image: Thumbwheel]

A quick search indicates you may be able to find thumbwheels cheaper than the device you have selected, if 10 positions are not a firm requirement.

Another reason for going with thumbwheels is that they are less obtrusive than knob / shaft devices, hence allowing sleeker enclosures!

Comment: OP's switch is for top-mount, these thumbwheels are for side mount. Any nice top-mount ones you can suggest?

Comment: @ExcitingProjects Top mount isn't a requirement for me, but 10 channels is. I can/have found other switches, I was just curious about this type.

Comment: @helloworld922 Lol! I was asking for top mount for my own similar project requirement!

Answer (score 3):

The switches with screwdriver slot are typically used for settings that need to be fixed most of the time and adjusted only infrequently.  Think of a selector switch on a rear panel of a fixed industrial device, which sets an address of the device on some modbus.  The fact that this switch needs a tool to turn it prevents an accidental change of setting.

I think that there wouldn't be an [official] knob for this switch.  But, like the O.P. wrote, there are other selector switches with knobs.